# Count letters not preceded by another letter

Tags: javascript, regex

How to implement the following count in JavaScript RegEx? -

Get the count of letter `B` occurrences that are not **immediately** preceded by letter `A`.

Examples:

- `AB B AB` => 1
- `B AB B` => 2
- `A B A B` => 2
- `BBB` => 3

**SOLUTION**

After much experimenting with the answers given here I found that in my example there are no RegEx solutions worth using. All solutions that were offered somehow result in the code significantly slower than a simple algorithmic approach.

Comment: shouldn't AB A AB => 0 ?

Comment: @marvel308, yes, corrected, sorry.

Comment: would the input have spaces ?

Comment: `[^Aa][Bb]` would this work ?

Comment: what about A B ?

Comment: how about this input `AB B AB BB-B` ? what should be the count?

Comment: @CaptainDaVinci that fails for example 2 where B doesn't have any symbols in front of it.

Comment: cases where B is preceded by a whitespace are always true ?

Comment: @marvel308 yes, I emphasized it with word **immediately**.

Comment: Then negative look behind should be helpful here, try this: `(?<![aA])[Bb]`

Comment: won't work in javascript

Comment: @CaptainDaVinci apparently, those things (look-behind) doesn't work in JavaScript.

Comment: If you want to count you could use str.match() as pointed out in the comment of my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work as suggested by Hassan Imam in the comments

```js
function check(str){
 const regex = /(AB{0,1})| /g;
 const subst = '';
 const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
    console.log(result.length);
}
check('AB B AB');
check('B AB B');
check('B A B B');
check('A B A B');
check('BBB');
```

Comment: where index = 2, since I want to count the 2nd group

Comment: How about this `str.match(/(^|[^A])B/g).length`?

Comment: I think that would be simpler.

Comment: Marvelous! The first one is what I was looking for! :) Thank you!

Comment: @marvel308 Ops, why doesn't it work for `BBB` -> 3 though? I didn't expect that. I have extended the question to include that as an example. I will re-accept the answer, if you can fix that issue. Thank you!

Comment: I did some changes, does this work for you, had to reverse string since javascript doesn't support negative look behind but supports negative lookahead

Comment: Reversing the string seems like a very inefficient operation. I asked the original question for the reason of replacing an algorithm with regex, but with all the reversing and all I end up with something that's way slower than just a simple algorithm. Maybe be I shouldn't have bothered in the first place... But I do appreciate the effort you made!

Comment: I made another attempt, I think this should perform well, the solution is quite simple now

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to use the negative lookbehind `(?<!A)B` in Javascript.
It'll work in Php, Python but not in Javascript. (https://regex101.com/r/MZhqSL/1)
Straight-forward way:

```js
var s = "AB B AB BB-B", count = 0;
    
for (i=0, l=s.length; i<l; i++) {
    if (s[i] === "B" && (i == 0 || s[i-1] !== "A")) count++;
}
    
console.log(count);
```

Comment: But I asked specifically for a RegEx solution.

Comment: @vitaly-t, you are not able to use the negative lookbehind `(?<!A)B` in Javascript. You can't do that. It'll work in Php, Python but not in Javascript. https://regex101.com/r/MZhqSL/1

Comment: As per the answer that I accepted, there was no need for a negative look back: `/(^|[^A])B/g`.

Comment: @vitaly-t, that won't work for double `B` occurences. like `AB B AB BB`

Comment: Thank you for spotting that. I have amended the question with such an example.

Comment: In the end I found it to be the best solution, as any RegEx approach resulted in slower performance. See the solution I amended in the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't support negative lookbehinds as far as I can tell, so I think your best bet is to do reverse the string and use a negative lookahead.

```js
function lookBehind(str) { //returns integer
  //split string into array
  //use <Array>.reverse()
  //Join array into string
  str = str.split('').reverse().join('');
  //reversed string ^
  return str.match(/b(?!(a))/gi).length; //the "i" flag makes the regex case insensitive.
}
console.log(lookBehind("AB B AB")); //1
console.log(lookBehind("B AB B")); //2
console.log(lookBehind("A B A B")); //2
```

[More about lookarounds.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)